# MySQL best way to store long strings

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for some advice on the best way to store long strings of data from the mySQL experts.

I have a general purpose table which is used to store any kind of data, by which I mean it should be able to hold alphanumeric and numeric data.
Currently, the table structure is simple with an ID and the actual data stored in a single column as follows:

```
id INT(11)
data VARCHAR(128)
```

I now have a requirement to store a larger amount of data (up to 500 characters) and am wondering whether the best way would be to simply increase the varchar column size, or whether I should add a new column (a TEXT type column?) for the times I need to store longer strings.

If any experts out there has any advice I'm all ears!
My preferred method would be to simply increase the varchar column, but that's because I'm lazy.
The mySQL version I'm running is 5.0.77.

I should mention the new 500 character requirement will only be for the odd record; most records in the table will be not longer than 50 characters.
I thought I'd be future-proofing by making the column 128. Shows how much I knew!

Comment: Use longtext datatype..

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Its really important to know what you intend to do with this data, do you manipulate it in anyway with a query or just store and retrieve the whole amount?

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys, with regards to what I do with the data, I just store and retrieve the whole amount

Comment: longblob = no character set might be better if you store PDFs for example - also creating a database with just one table will turn out to be bad at some point, as you have to code your own database system around it. It kind of defeats the idea of a database system.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is not a question that has a "correct" answer. There is no "infinite length" text storage type in MySQL. You could use `LONGTEXT`, but that still has an (absurdly high) upper limit. Yet if you do, you're kicking your DBMS in the teeth for having to deal with that absurd blob of a column for your 50-character text. Not to mention the fact that you hardly do anything with it.

So, most futureproofness(TM) is probably offered by `LONGTEXT`. But it's also a very bad method of resolving the issue. Honestly, I'd revisit the application requirements. Storing strings that have no "domain" (as in, being well-defined in their application) and arbitrary length is not one of the strengths of RDBMS.

If I'd want to solve this on the "application design" level, I'd use NoSQL key-value store for this (and I'm as anti-NoSQL-hype as they get, so you know it's serious), even though I recognize it's a rather expensive change for such a minor change. But if this is an indication of what your DBMS is eventually going to hold, it might be more prudent to switch now to avoid this same problem hundred times in the future. Data domain is very important in RDBMS, whereas it's explicitly sidelined in non-relational solutions, which seems to be what you're trying to solve here.

Stuck with MySQL? Just increase it to `VARCHAR(1000)`. If you have no requirements for your data, it's irrelevant what you do anyway.

Comment: Just a note that if it's only 500 characters, `TEXT` will work just fine.

Comment: `TEXT` is both heavy to use for "only" 500 characters and neither does the OP know if 500 is the upper limit. The answer depends on whether you're using MyISAM or InnoDB, but for columns where the text is rapidly accessible, `VARCHAR` is faster, since it stores data inline (InnoDB also stores `TEXT` inline up to row length limit, 2^16). So, depends on application, but `TEXT` is only ever always better if you can't put a stable upper limit on column length.

Comment: Agreed, @Naltharial. Just wanted to ensure the suggestions of `LONGTEXT` weren't the only reference to `TEXT` here - instead of `LONGTEXT`, `TEXT` will likely be much more in the realm of likely solution for OP, although the true solution is hopefully tightening the requirements.

Comment: To whom it may concern - please do not edit an answer without cause. The VARCHAR limit is subject to row length and character encodings. Likewise, don't add or remove words that change the meaning of the answer itself.

Comment: `Data domain is very important in RDBMS` - Can anyone please explain this? or point to any good resource?

Comment: It means that relational databases require your data to be well-defined and, generally, normalized to work the way they're supposed to work. It's just a basic property of relational data.

Answer (score 7):

Careful if using text. TEXT data is not stored in the database server’s memory, therefore, whenever you query TEXT data, MySQL has to read from it from the disk, which is much slower in comparison with CHAR and VARCHAR as it cannot make use of indexes.The better way to store long string will be nosql databases

Answer (score 3):

We can use `varchar(<maximum_limit>)`. The maximum limit that we can pass is 65535 bytes.

Note: This maximum length of a VARCHAR is shared among all columns except TEXT/BLOB columns and the character set used.