# MS SQL SERVER - suitable datatype for storing large String

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am doing a project for a clinical laboratory. I am using java, hibernate and sql server for my project. In some cases I need to store large amount of string for certain reports in database. Can anyone suggest which type of datatype is to be used in db for storing a huge amount of string data (here I am unaware of the size of string because in each case it may differ). Is there any possibility to store such a huge data in db(SQL SERVER). Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL best way to store long strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406299/mysql-best-way-to-store-long-strings)

Comment: The SQL server varchar(MAX) and nvarchar(MAX) data types can hold up to 2GB of data.  If the "reports are often large" you might consider using the a FileTable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

Since `NVARCHAR` uses 2 bytes per character, that's approx. 1 billion characters can be stored.

The max size for a column of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is `2GB` of storage.