# How To Save Long Text in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to store a string in Mysql database whose length is 1000000 (1 Million characters).
Which datatype should I use? Which is best method for this ?

Comment: Either use a different type of db such as mongo or store it on harddisk

Comment: Look for datatype 'text'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406299/mysql-best-way-to-store-long-strings

Comment: here is a helpful resource for your question [**LINK**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text) also just so you know, you are most likely getting the downvotes because you didn't seem to do any research, a simple google search ("mysql store long text") shows that the first two results are the answers you want.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use one of the [`BLOB` types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html). Pick one that suits your needs.

For 1MB of data you'll probably go with `LONGTEXT`.